Case insensitive section in ConfigParser
I am trying to set up ConfigParser so that it would be case insensitive to section input value when using e.g. parser.items(section, raw, vars) or parser.get(section, option, **kwargs). Let's say my configuration file dummyConfig.cfg is:
[DEFAULT]
a = 1
b = 2
c = 3

[section1]
b = 5
d = 4

[  Section 2  ]
b = 3
d = 4
e = 5

then parser.items("section1") would return the same result as parser.items("SECTION1").
My understanding is that ConfigParser.SECTCRE should allow me to do exactly that. I played a bit with the exemple in the in the doc to be sure that I understood and indeed, the following script
from configparser import ConfigParser
import re
config_dummy = ConfigParser()
config_dummy.SECTCRE = re.compile(r"\[ *(?P<header>[^]]+?) *\]")
config_dummy.read('dummyConfig.cfg')
config_dummy.items('Section 2')

does return key-values from [  Section 2  ].
As i am not well versed in regular expression pattern, I made some test to have the proper one for my case:
import re
re_object = re.compile(r"\[(?P<header>[MYHEADER]+?)\]")
a_header = "[myheader]"
re_object.match(a_header)

There is no match as expected
import re
re_object = re.compile(r"\[(?P<header>[MYHEADER]+?)\]", flags=re.IGNORECASE)
a_header = "[myheader]"
re_object.match(a_header)

In this case, I have one: <re.Match object; span=(0, 10), match='[myheader]'> .
Going back to my case, I thus thought that the following would work:
from configparser import ConfigParser
import re
config_dummy = ConfigParser()
config_dummy.SECTCRE = re.compile(r"\[(?P<header>[^]]+?)\]", flags=re.IGNORECASE)
config_dummy.read('dummyConfig.cfg')
config_dummy.items('SECTION1')

But I get NoSectionError: No section: 'SECTION1' . So I am puzzle and would be quite interested to know what I am getting wrong there.

IGNORECASE cannot make a difference when no alpha characters are matched. A Python regexp is not capable of converting to upper or lower case (\L and \U from some other languages are not supported). I see no solution except something awkward like dumping the config to a dict and post-process that dict and maybe load it back.

Thanks a lot, this was quite helpful as I would have lost some much time for nothing. I did thing differently in the end to be able to be case insensitive.
